# Spectrum of a product of a symmetric positive definite matrix and a positive definite operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathbf H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

I want to find an example of a $2\times 2$ real symmetric positive definite matrix $M$ and a positive definite bounded operator $A : \mathbf H \times \mathbf H\to \mathbf H \times \mathbf H$ such that the spectrum of $A$ is discrete but the spectrum of $MA$ is not discrete (could be an interval for example).

Comment: $A=1$, and then take any $M$ with non-discrete spectrum. (Here $\sigma(A)=\{ 1\}$ is discrete as a set, though actually the spectrum is not discrete in the more natural sense of empty essential spectrum. But then a bounded self-adjoint operator always has non-empty essential spectrum.)

Comment: Excuse me. $M$ is assumed to be a $2\times 2$ symmetric positive definite matrix so it has discrete spectrum which consists of its eigenvalues.

Comment: What definition of "discrete spectrum" do you use?

Comment: @JochenGlueck: $\sigma_d$ = isolated eigenvalues of finite multiplicity, I have the advantage of never having seen any other definition.

Comment: @SAKLY: You wrote your Hilbert space is infinite-dimensional, so there are certainly (positive, if desired) operators without any discrete spectrum.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Yes, sure - but as you noted, a bounded operator in infinite dimensions cannot have this property for every spectral value. So my intention was to ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Regarding your discussion with the OP: I believe they wan't $M$ to be an element of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ and then interpret it as an operator on $H \times H$. Of course, the eigenvalues of this operator don't have finite multiplicity - but the spectrum is discrete as a topological set and maybe this is what they mean.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @SAKLY: Ok. Please note, though, that this definition of discrete spectrum is rather uncommon (as pointed out by Christian Remling) and implies that $A$ is a linear combination of finitely many orthogonal projections. Could you please confirm again that you really have this quite restrictive class of operators in mind for $A$?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yes, if possible, we can restrict ourselves to this particular case for the operator $A$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Another attempted rescue operation would be to interpret "discrete" = pure point spectrum, which is actually quite common (though unfortunate) terminology in physics.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Yes, I had assumed $A: H\to H$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Apparently one can indeed construct such an example by taking an infinite diagonal operator that consists of matrices which almost commute; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to construct such an example:

For each integer $n \ge 1$ consider the matrices $A_n, M_n \in \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ given by
$$
  M_n =
  e_1 e_1^T
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
  \qquad \text{and} \qquad 
  A_n = 
  f_n f_n^T
  ,
$$
where $e_1 \in \mathbb{C}^2$ if the first canonical unit vector and where $f_n \in \mathbb{C}^2$ is a vector of Euclidean norm $1$ that satisfies $e_1^T f_n = \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}$.
Both $M_n$ and $A_n$ are orthogonal projections.
The matrix
$$
  M_n A_n 
  = 
  e_1 (e_1^T f_n) f_n^T
$$
has spectrum $\{0, (e_1^T f_n)^2\} = \{0, 1-\frac{1}{n}\}$.

Now consider the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}; \mathbb{C}^2)$, which can be identified with $H \times H$ for $H := \ell^2(\mathbb{N}; \mathbb{C})$ by splitting each copy of $\mathbb{C}^2$ into its first and second component. On $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}; \mathbb{C}^2) = H \times H$ we define operators $A$ and $M$ by multiplying each sequence with the operator sequence $(A_n)$ and $(M_n)$, respectively.

Both operators $A$ and $M$ are orthogonal projections; in particular, they are positive semidefinite, self-adjoint, and have spectrum $\{0,1\}$. The operator $M$ can be written as the matrix
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \operatorname{id} & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
with respect to the decomposition $H \times H$. However, the spectrum of $MA$ contains all the numbers $1 - \frac{1}{n}$ and thus accumulates at $1$.

If you want positive definite rather than positive semidefinite operators, you can modiy the construction of $A_n$ and $M_n$ a bit to have the sequences $(A_n)$ and $(M_n)$ bounded below by a fixed multiple of the identity matrix (one just needs to explicitly compute the spectra of $M_nA_n$ then, which is a bit more computational work since those will be rank-$2$ rather than rank-$1$ operators.